# using AsyncTask with mediaplayer in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i am developing an android application i have a function to play music from online streaming it take a time to make the application lunch up so i need to give the media player task to a thread to make the application lunch quickly and the thread take the media player 
so when i make this operation the application give me an exception that `mediaplayer.prepare()`  need the main thread so i will post what i try in my code:

```
public void playsong()
{
            mediaplayer mp =new mediaplayer();
            String currentUrl = sora.getUrl(this);  
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(currentUrl);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

}




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        initView();
        thread.start();

         }


Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
          playSong();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to use AsyncTask...

```
class PalyMusic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {


      //your background process


        return (null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        //here you can call your mp.prepare();
    }

}
```

and for calling this

```
   new PalyMusic().execute();
```

Don't forget to add this to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy and proper way use `prepareAsync()` method rather `prepare()`

```
public void playsong()
    {
        try {
            final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            String currentUrl = sora.getUrl(this);
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(currentUrl);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.prepareAsync();

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: The `prepareAsync` needs to be *after* the `setOnPreparedListener`.